# How can I get data from Form when the view is made by *ngFor in Angular?

Tags: angular

I know ngModel can help sometimes,but it's just for only element.My view is made by *ngFor,so,the ngModel will be same if I use it.my code as flowing.

```
            <div *ngIf="panel.type==3 ||panel.type==4 ">
                <div *ngFor="let question of panel.questions;let index=index;">
                    <h3>{{index+1}}、{{question.title}}</h3>
                    <nz-input nzType="textarea" [nzAutosize]="true"></nz-input>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I need to get the value of every input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily.

```
<div *ngFor="let question of panel.questions;let index=index;trackBy: customTB">
  <h3>{{index+1}}、{{questions[index].title}}</h3>
  <nz-input nzType="textarea" [nzAutosize]="true" [(ngModel)]="questions[index].answer"></nz-input>
</div>
```

In your component,

```
customTB(index, item) { return index; }
```

This way, you create a custom trackby function, that will be used to track the items of your array (you need a custom trackby function when you work with primitives values such as strings).